# Cordova: How can you save a local file to device disk

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am struggling with a Cordova/PhoneGap issue that I can't find the solution to for the life of me:

**Here's the problem:**
I have a series of PDFs in my application which I build into iOS/Android and I want to be able to display them. The method doesn't matter - the PDFs need to be accessible to the end-user.

Here is a list of methods I have tried:

- **PDFjs.** I have tried this plugin to render PDFs, however it is blurry and not readable.
- **InAppBrowser plugin (_black, _system).** The InAppBrowser plugin does not support rendering PDFs in all browsers, nor does it allow you to open an application resorce into a _system window so that the native functionality will be executed (download/render depending on device).
- **FileTransfer plugin.** I can't seem to be able to execute a download to the device fileSystem from local application resources.
- **Anchor 'download' attribute.** Download links to local resources do not allow me to download files to the application system.

Every StackOverflow (or other) resource that I can find revolves around saving files to the device from a webserver, not an application.

**Specifications:** Cordova v5.0, Target devices: iOS 7&8, Android 4.1 - 5 (so yes the Android browser is included).

I would greatly appreciate any input regarding this.

Comment: how about reading the file in binary string and save it using file api?

Comment: Would this add a user download notification? The end aim is to allow users to view PDFs which are saved locally in the application.

Comment: I don't quite understand, for example if I put an MP3 sound file in the same folder of index.html, I can play the sound in the index.html.  so if I replace that MP3 with the PDF, you can't access those PDF?

Comment: I can access the PDF - however there is no reliable cross-browser support for PDFs once you take Android into consideration.

My end aim is to make those PDFs accessible in some way, however I'm stumped as to how.

Comment: well, spend some times and convert it to images then it's 100% guarantee!